# Up down gestures interruption with left right scroll gestures

Tags: java, android, gesture

I am making an android application in which I am using `onScroll` gestures to increase or decrease brightness on Upward and downward scroll and on left to right scroll I am increasing and decreasing Song duration `onTouch` on screen, when I scroll upward and downward on screen its working fine but a little bit interruption with left to right scroll which creates problem. When I scroll left to right it works fine but some interruptions with up to down gestures which is used on screen touch. Please tell me what should I do????

Here is my code.

```
if (Math.abs(deltaX) < Math.abs(deltaY)) {
    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
        if (deltaY > leftSidelastX) {
            leftSidelastX = deltaY;
            upBrightness();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide up");
        } else {
            leftSidelastX = deltaY;
            downBrightness();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide down");
        }
    }
} else {
    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
        if (deltaX > leftSidelastX) {
            leftSidelastX = deltaX;
            leftScroll();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide left");
        } else {
            leftSidelastX = deltaX;
            rightScroll();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide right");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer If Else structure is the problem. When you swipe Up and down and move it a little to the side you automatically stop the swipe up/down and go to the swipe left/right.

Depending on what you want, you can either remove the If Else structure, when it should be possible to do both at the same time or you need to set a variable if you are currently swiping up and down, set this variable at begin of swiping and always ask for this variable instead. Than you need to reset it on stop swiping.

Solution 1:

```
if (Math.abs(deltaY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
    if (deltaY > leftSidelastX) {
        leftSidelastX = deltaY;
        upBrightness();
        Log.i("", "Left side Slide up");
    } else {
        leftSidelastX = deltaY;
        downBrightness();
        Log.i("", "Left side Slide down");
    }
}
if (Math.abs(deltaX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
    if (deltaX > leftSidelastX) {
        leftSidelastX = deltaX;
        leftScroll();
        Log.i("", "Left side Slide left");
    } else {
        leftSidelastX = deltaX;
        rightScroll();
        Log.i("", "Left side Slide right");
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

Create variable scroll as empty String as member variable.

```
if(scroll.equals("UP/DOWN"){
    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
        if (deltaY > leftSidelastX) {
            leftSidelastX = deltaY;
            upBrightness();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide up");
        } else {
            leftSidelastX = deltaY;
            downBrightness();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide down");
        }
    }
} else if(scroll.equals("LEFT/RIGHT")){
    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
        if (deltaX > leftSidelastX) {
            leftSidelastX = deltaX;
            leftScroll();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide left");
        } else {
            leftSidelastX = deltaX;
            rightScroll();
            Log.i("", "Left side Slide right");
        }
    }
}else{
    if (Math.abs(deltaX) < Math.abs(deltaY)) {
        scroll = "LEFT/RIGHT";
    }else{
        scroll = "UP/DOWN";
    }
}
```

Comment: So please tell me which solution you want and what exactly is the problem, then I can try to help.

Comment: Sorry To say that your both solutions are not working at some instance, when I scroll up/down then left/right is interrupting. When I start from initial point till ending point and come back to initial point it works fine but when I go back from starting it interrupts.

Comment: Actually I have split window screen in two pieces left half for volume and right half for brightness for scroll up down both side  and left to right and right to left for song duration but when i am scrolling up down left side  continuously so suddenly left to right is interrupts ..Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to make like mx video player give me some help please